# How to make multple function calls to each element in observable stream return observable stream of "new" objects

Tags: angularjs, promise, rxjs, observable

I have an expression that takes an observable stream of posts and for each post evaluates a "posterName" and merges back in to the original post.

Before returning the post, is there a way to call another function to evaluate a second attribute (whether the post has been liked by current user) and then merge that back in with the posterName and original post.

Please see code and comment below

```
this.fService.postList$.pipe( 
      switchMap(_posts => { // switchMap to subscribe to inner

        const getUsers$ = _posts
          .map(post => // array map comments into posterName fetch
      
            this.fService.getUserName(post.uid).pipe(
              // once you have the username, rx map back into the comment with the username assigned
              map(userName => ({...post, posterName: userName.first_name + " " + userName.last_name})),

              catchError((err) => {
                // Handle specific error for this call
                console.log(err)
                return of({...post, posterName: "Anonymous"})
              }),

              first()
            )

            //Where can I write a second function that takes the same posts ID
            //and return a promise that I can "then" so I merge the resolved
            //value in to the post i.e ({...post,posterName: somename , thirdThing: somevalue}) 
        )

    

        return forkJoin(...getUsers$); // forkJoin them all together for parallel execution
      })).subscribe(data => { //doing stuff})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this close to what you are looking for?

It gets all of the posts, for each of the posts, it gets the user and all of the todos.

- It first retrieves all of the posts. Then it pipes the retrieved
  posts through a `switchMap` to flatten the result.
- It uses forkJoin to combine the results for each post.
- It uses forkJoin a second time to combine the associated user of the
  post and their todos (which would be their likes in your scenario).
- It then maps the result of the forkJoin into a structure consisting
  of the post, the userName, and the list of todos for that user.
- The template uses an async pipe to subscribe to the postData$
  structure and access the desired piece of that structure.

NOTE: This won't be exactly the same for your code because I used a public user/post/todo API so I could ensure the following code worked.

```
  // Get all posts
  // Get the user of each post
  // Get the todos for each user
  postData$ = this.http.get<Post[]>(this.postUrl).pipe(
    switchMap(posts =>
      forkJoin(
        posts.map(post =>
          forkJoin([
            this.http.get<User>(`${this.userUrl}/${post.userId}`),
            this.http.get<ToDo[]>(`${this.todoUrl}?userId=${post.userId}`)
          ]).pipe(
            map(([user, todos]) => ({
              post: post,
              userName: user.name,
              todos: todos
            }))
          )
        )
      )
    )
  );


export interface Post {
  userId: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  body: string;
}

export interface ToDo {
  userId: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  completed: boolean;
}

export interface User {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  username: string;
  email: string;
  website: string;
}

export interface PostData {
  post: Post;
  userName: string;
  toDos: ToDo[];
}
```

I have a stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-todos-posts-forkjoin-deborahk

Comment: Thanks a lot! Seems like I'm close, but the observables are not completing.Where would add a  "first()" to force complete the inner obsevables?

Comment: Wait!!!! OMG You're Deborah Kurata! I'm literally doing this with your Angular:Getting Started course on PluralSight by my side!!! BIG FAN!!

Comment: Thanks! If these are retrieving data, then they will complete without needing to do a .first(). If you are doing something else, feel free to fork my stackblitz and modify it to more closely demonstrate your issue/question.

Comment: I have edited your response to reflect my current problem. I don't get any errors but the complete function on the subscribe method never gets called. I know on of my  firebase observables does not complete until I explicitly call take(1)/ first()

Comment: After 30 mins I managed to get it working! Thanks Deborah!! Answer updated

Comment: Glad you got it working. To add a take or first to any of the Observables, you could just do it like this: `this.http.get<User>(`${this.userUrl}/${post.userId}`).pipe(first())`.